# How to get Aldia fight if Nashandra is dead for good?

Tags: dark-souls-2

According to [wiki](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/aldia-scholar-of-the-first-sin) one can get Aldia as a boss after defeating Vendrik and Nashandra. My problem is that I've defeated Nashandra before Vendrik. Can I get Aldia as a boss in this case?

Now I've killed Vendrik and come back to the Throne of Want and there is not Aldia. Meanwhile I'm sure I've met him at Dragon Shrine. Is there any other conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, It can't be done in that order. For it to work properly you have to

1. Kill Vendrick
2. Talk to Aldia in all of his locations
3. Kill Nashandra
4. Aldia will appear

This is fixable with a bonfire ascetic. Using an Ascetic on the "King's Gate" bonfire respawns Nashandra and the Throne Watchers. This unfortunately also puts the fight (including the one with Aldia) into NG+.